# How to get handle on Wistia video using API after it is injected into DOM

Tags: javascript, iframe, wistia

I am lazy loading Wistia videos and they are injected into the DOM after a click of an image. I am trying to get handles on the videos in order to pause videos when a new video starts playing, but Wistia API callback is not firing.

```
function getAllVideos() {
        window._wq = window._wq || [];
        console.log(window._wq)
        window._wq.push({
            id: "_all",
            onEmbedded: function(video) {
                console.log('inside ready');
            }
        })
        console.log(window._wq)
    }
```

I am always receiving an empty array. `Wistia.api.all()` also returns an empty array. It might be because of async? I am injecting the iframe by making a call to the Wistia api like so:

```
$slide.getJSON('http://fast.wistia.com/oembed/?url=http://home.wistia.com/medias/' + embed + '&format=json')
                .then(res => {
                    var thumbnail = new Image(); // create image to hold thumbnail
                    thumbnail.src = res.thumbnail_url; // set thumbnail source
                    var videoContainer = document.getElementById('slick-slide0' + i); // each slide get video container
                    videoContainer.appendChild(thumbnail);
                    videoContainer.innerHTML += '<div class="play-button"></div>';
                    var slider = document.getElementById('slick-slide-control0' + i);

                    // on click of each image, create iframe, remove image, insert iframe
                    videoContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        var iframeEmbed = document.getElementById('{{parent_custom_widget_name}}_' + i).innerHTML;
                        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
                        iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', 'true');
                        iframe.setAttribute('src', '//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/' + iframeEmbed + '?autoplay=true');
                        this.innerHTML = '';
                        this.appendChild(iframe);
                        getAllVideos();
                    });

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create object of wistia using
    `var wistiaObj = Wistia.api("<id_of_wistia_tag>");`

After that you can call function,
    `wistiaObj.play();`
    `wistiaObj.time();`

you can refer this: https://wistia.com/support/developers/player-api
Hope it helps you.